# How to filter out YouTube's content-blocked videos from REST API search.list results

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, uiwebview, youtube-api

I am making an iOS app in Swift that will allow the user to search and play youtube videos using youtube's rest API. To do this, I am using a UIWebView and YouTube iFrame. The problem is a lot of videos have been blocked from being played such as videos by VEVO and certain record labels. I want to know if there is a way to filter out the search results so the blocked videos don't show? I have tried setting videoSyndicated and videoEmbeddable to true with no luck. Or, is there a way around the content block?

Here is the code I am using to search:

```
var searchUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=20&q=\(video)&type=video&videoEmbeddable=true&videoSyndicated=true&key=MYAPIKEY"
let url = NSURL(string: searchUrl)
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

if data != nil {
    var json = JSON(data: data!)

    for i in 0..<20 {
        if let videoId = json["items", i, "id", "videoId"].string {
            videoIds.append(videoId)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to load the video:

```
let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='200' height='200' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I could actually get it to play the blocked videos by setting the origin to a working URL.  For example, in the htmlString variable I added `&origin='http:www.example.com'`

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter for that in your search request, but once you get the list of IDs that match your request, you can see if it's blocked by using the `videos.list` call. You can check if it's [rejected](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.rejectionReason) (by looking at the status) or [blocked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.regionRestriction.blocked[]) (by looking at contentDetails).

Some possible reasons a video might be rejected:

> - claim
> - copyright
> - termsOfUse
> - trademark

Comment: I just looked at those and they don't say if it won't play, only if it was rejected for upload or blocked in certain countries.  I tried the API explorer with a video I know is blocked and they both would make me assume it isn't blocked.

Comment: What results did you get for that video?

Comment: `"contentDetails": { "duration": "PT5M32S", "dimension": "2d", "definition": "hd", "caption": "false", "licensedContent": true, "regionRestriction": { "blocked": [ "DE" ] } }, "status": { "uploadStatus": "processed", "privacyStatus": "public", "license": "youtube", "embeddable": true, "publicStatsViewable": true }`

Comment: Yes, but I am in the US and it is still blocked.

Comment: What's the ID for the video?

Comment: Medicated by Wiz Khalifa - jLPvmwfklp8

Comment: I am also in the US and it isn't blocked for me. Are you using a VPN or something similar?

Comment: It's only blocked when playing in a third-party app such as the one I'm making.

Comment: The way I mentioned above should work if you were just working with the Youtube API. I don't know of any workarounds for an issue due to it being a third party app.